# html forms and inputs not validating on w3c validator

Tags: html, forms, validation

I just started working with forms and inputs http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp and they work fine as far as I can tell, but they cause a load of errors when I run it through W3C validation service.  http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input
The code validates fine when I remove the forms and inputs. The only thing I can think of, is that the forms and inputs are not entirely html, as I don`t yet know what the name= does
Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>login</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/login.css'>
</head>

<body>

    <div id ="header">
        <h1>log in</h1>
    </div>

    <div id ="name">
        <form>
            editors name: <input type="text" name="name">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="pswd">
        <form>
            password: <input type="password" name="pwd">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="options">
        <h3>Or</h3>
    </div>  
    <div id="wayBack">
        <a href="www.adrianhoulewebprojects.com/easyEdit.html">Return to page</a>   
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to achieve is this...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>login</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/login.css'>
</head>

<body>

    <div id ="header">
        <h1>log in</h1>
    </div>

    <form action="/">
        <div id ="name">
            editors name: <input type="text" name="name">
        </div>
        <div id="pswd">
            password: <input type="password" name="pwd">
        </div>
    </form>

    <div id="options">
        <h3>Or</h3>
    </div>  
    <div id="wayBack">
        <a href="www.adrianhoulewebprojects.com/easyEdit.html">Return to page</a>   
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The fields should be contained with in one form so that they get submitted together. The errors were raised because it's not valid to have text (editors name / password) as a direct child of a  FORM element

A more semantic solution would be...

```
<form action="/">
    <div>
        <label for="input_name">editors name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="input_name" />

        <p>It's completely valid to have text here inside a P tag</p>

        <label for="input_password">password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="input_password" />
    </div>
</form>
```

This would allow the user to click on the label in order to focus the corresponding form field

Comment: You also need an `action` for the form

Comment: I learned something today, I thought it was method that was required :P

Comment: Perfect that is exactly what I was trying to do. So are you saying that I cannot have more than one form. What if I need to add a bunch of content between input fields

Comment: You can have as many forms as you like on the page but only the inputs contained within the form will submitted together. If you need text inside a form you can use a < p > tag (see updated solution above

Comment: by action do you mean a submit button, yeah i dont know what i was thinking when i forgot to add one

Comment: He means ... < form action="/" > which tells the form which page to submit the data to

Comment: Got it. Found everything I needed on the same page I was already looking at, just didint understand it at the time. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp